# Navigation bar moves back after reloading the website

Tags: html, css

I made a navigation bar with some animation and it's moving back every time I reload the website. It should move back only if its fully open to width: 275 and only when I release my mouse out of it (opposite of hover)

CSS:

```
#navigation {width: 5px; height: calc(100vh - 50px); opacity: 0; text-align: center; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; animation: pulse-out 0.5s;}
#navigation .hidden > h3 {color: #FFFFFF; text-transform: uppercase;}
#navigation .hidden a {color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none; display: block; padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 14px;}
#navigation .hidden a:hover {color: #8e44ad;}
#navigation:hover {width: 275px; background: #171C21; animation: pulse-in 0.5s; opacity: 1;}
@keyframes pulse-in {
    0% {
        width: 5px;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        width: 275px;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes pulse-out {
    0% {
        width: 275px;
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        width: 5px;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

How can I fix it? Live preview: http://awesomeness.adam.zur.io/
Also the text should not disappear this way, it should firstly disappear and then slowly change its width back to 5px.

Answer (score 0):

You put

```
#navigation {
width: 5px; 
height: calc(100vh - 50px); 
opacity: 0; 
text-align: center; 
padding-top: 10px; 
padding-bottom: 10px; 
animation: pulse-out 0.5s;}
```

and animation starts when you refresh the page. That's why you see how menu is closing (cause pulse-out is working). Delete this style and everything will be refreshed well. It'll be better to use JS hover instead (on hover start animation pulse-in and start animation pulse-out when you leave mouse from menu)